# Etiquetas sobrepostas

Tags: html, css, span

Saudações.

Com o seguinte código...

https://jsfiddle.net/WRobynson/n10pttbb/2/

As etiquetas ficam sobrepostas quando a tela é diminuída. Gostaria que ficasse uma em baixo da outra. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se a resposta foi correta, a melhor forma de agradecer é marcando ✓.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro separar cada etiqueta dentro de um *container* (um elemento `span` com uma classe) e adicionar `display: inline-block`.

Por que `inline-block`?

Um `span` por padrão é apenas `inline`, e a linha que ele ocupa é apenas a do texto dentro dele. O `inline-block` dá uma *altura de linha* ao elemento de acordo com ele realmente ocupa, logo o que vier abaixo não irá sobrepô-lo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então ficaria assim o código:

```css
.Lab1 {
 padding: 6px 12px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #555;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #eee;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-right-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
   display: inline-block;
}

.Lab2 {
 padding: 6px 12px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #555;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-left-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
 /* white-space: nowrap; já não é mais necessário */
   display: inline-block;

}

.container{
  display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

/* div apenas para exemplo*/
div{
   width: 100px;
}
```

```html
Dentro da div com 100px:
<div>
<span class="container">
   <span class='Lab1'>1º</span><span class='Lab2'>Primeiro</span>
</span>
<span class="container">
   <span class='Lab1'>2º</span><span class='Lab2'>Segundo</span>
</span>
<span class="container">
   <span class='Lab1'>3º</span><span class='Lab2'>Terceiro</span>
</span>
</div>
<br><br>
Fora da div:
<br>
<span class="container">
   <span class='Lab1'>1º</span><span class='Lab2'>Primeiro</span>
</span>
<span class="container">
   <span class='Lab1'>2º</span><span class='Lab2'>Segundo</span>
</span>
<span class="container">
   <span class='Lab1'>3º</span><span class='Lab2'>Terceiro</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Só pra deixar mais claro, para ele: os elementos inline possuem largura e altura correspondente ao conteúdo, mas não podem receber valores nas propriedades width e height.

Quando trocamos o display para inline-block, o elemento passa a poder receber valores no width e height, além de não ocupar (por padrão) toda a largura possível, como fazem os elementos com display: block;

Comment: @JoãoLucas Isso mesmo.